# Ordenar una tabla con veces que es referenciada en otra

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Veran, tengo 2 tablas, una llamada Enlaces, con estos valores:

```
Schema::create('enlaces', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('juego_id');
    $table->foreign('juego_id')->references('id')->on('juegos');
    $table->unsignedInteger('contenido_id');
    $table->foreign('contenido_id')->references('id')->on('contenidos');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Y otra llamada Contenido:

```
Schema::create('contenidos', function (Blueprint $table){
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('nombre');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Estas tablas se relacionan por el valor contenido_id de Enlace, que apunta a Contenido.

Para saber cuantas veces es referenciado una fila de Contenido en una fila Enlace, tengo la función "contento":

```
public function contento(){
    $contenidos=Contenido::orderBy('nombre')->get();
    return view('listas.datos_contenido',compact('contenidos'));
}
```

Que apunta a esta vista:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<h1 class="text-center text-mute"><u>Lista de juegos por contenido:</u></h1>
    <div class="pl-5 pr-5">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-3 card card-body">
                @forelse($contenidos as $c)
                    <b><i>{{$c->nombre}}: {{count($c->enlaces)}}</i></b>
                    <hr>
                @empty
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <h1 class="text-center">¿¡No se ha creado ningún contenido aún!?</h1>
                </div>
            @endforelse
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Siendo la función "enlaces" el siguiente código en Contenido.php:

```
public function enlaces(){
    return $this->hasMany(Enlace::class);
}
```

Este es el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En si esto funciona, lo único es que esto ordena por nombre del contenido.
A mi lo que me interesa es que se ordene la lista de contenidos por el número de veces que es referenciado en la tabla Enlace.
¿Cómo se haria?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando deseas contar la cantidad de modelos relacionados en Laravel, la mejor forma de hacerlo es con el método withCount, el cual ni siquiera carga los modelos relacionados, solo los cuenta:

```
$contenidos = Contenido::withCount('enlaces')->get();
```

Esa sería la consulta básica, donde se obtiene una columna adicional `enlaces_count` que contiene dicho total.

La documentación: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models

---

En este caso no solo queremos obtener el total de los modelos relacionados, sino que también debe estar ordenado por dicho parámetro o columna, para lo cual usamos el método habitual de Eloquent/Query Builder:

```
$contenidos = Contenido::withCount('enlaces')
                ->orderBy('enlaces_count', 'desc') 
                ->get();
```

Para mostrarlo en la vista, sería así:

```
            @forelse($contenidos as $c)
                <b><i>{{$c->nombre}}: {{$c->enlaces_count)}}</i></b>
                <hr>
            @empty
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                  <h1 class="text-center">¿¡No se ha creado ningún contenido aún!?</h1>
                </div>
            @endforelse
```

Comment: Pues gracias, lo he conseguido ordenar.